# Changing CWD for Method Invoked via Java.Lang.Reflect

Tags: java, tomcat, reflection

I have a Java servlet that uses Reflection to invoke other Java methods. Some Java methods that I invoke generate files, and I want to be able to move those files to another location.

Currently, if an absolute path isn't supplied in the method (e.g. PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("prog.out")), the output file gets thrown into the bin directory of my Tomcat installation.

I've tried setting the CWD with the following code, where myDataDir is the directory I want the output files to go into:

```
File directory;
directory = new File(myDataDir.getPath()).getAbsoluteFile();
if (directory.exists() || directory.mkdirs()) {
    System.setProperty("user.dir", directory.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

I've even gone so far as to go into the code for the Java method I've written and print out what "user.dir" is from there. Even there it tells me that everything is set up properly (e.g. "user.dir" == /path/that/i/want). Nevertheless, when I invoke the method with reflection, the output file gets put in the bin directory.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before? Any pointers or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Some details:

- Running on Redhat 7.3
- Using Tomcat version 8.0.36
- Building with Maven 3.3.9
- Java 1.7.0

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot change the "current working directory" at runtime. But you don't need to use it at all. You need to detect if a supplied path is not absolute (should you even accept absolute paths? seems like a security issue), and then make it absolute by prefixing it with some root directory that you think is appropriate.

Comment: How can I check if a supplied path within a Java method is absolute? From my servlet's perspective, it knows nothing about the method it's running or any of the files that said method is creating. It's simply being told to invoke it.

Comment: If you want to run black-box code and need to provide them with a working directory, you need to fork off a new process (with its own JVM). At that point, it is probably better to rethink your design and have some standard mechanism for what these "plugins" can do and how to configure them.

Comment: Isn't that essentially what java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke does? Spin off a new Java process?

Comment: No. That just makes a method call.

Comment: " I want to be able to move those files to another location." If you have a way to at least find these files, you can move them to a new location after calling your black-box method.

Comment: That's my last resort... copying files that get thrown into the Tomcat's bin directory to the archive directory. I was just hoping that there was an easier way to have them be generated in that archive rather than having to copy them over.

Comment: It's really strange to me that Tomcat doesn't have a mechanism for handling this sort of situation..

Comment: Embeddable Java code is not supposed to just write to the current working directory, but take some kind of configuration where to put/read files. Improve the code you are calling into if you can.